# Google Calendar API - My calendars & Other calendars

Tags: google-calendar-api

In Google Calendar, one can see 2 categories of calendars namely, `My calendars` and `Other Calendars`. Is there a way to determine which calendars belong to `My calendars` and `Other calendars` using Google Calendar API?

I looked at the response from `gapi.client.calendar.events.list` but was unable to find anything that specifies which category a calendar belongs to.

Comment: `My Calendars` is a primary calendar while the `Other Calendars` is a secondary calendar. See [Calendar and Events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/events-calendars#primary_calendars_and_other_calendars).

To know whether the calendar is on the primary calendar or not you can use the `CalendarList` resource which returns a response with `primary` property which will return true if the calendar is in primary and false otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You should use .calendar.calendarList.list to retrieve the list of the calendars. If the accessRole says you are an owner for the calendar, then it's your calendar.

Comment: I have a Birthdays calendar under "my calendars" but its not owner role.

Comment: There are exceptions to all rules ;)